# Python - Get original function arguments in decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to write a "login_required" decorator for the views in a WSGI+Werkzeug application.

In order to do this, I need to get at the user's session, which is accessible via the Request object that is passed into the view methods.

I can't figure out how to get at that instance of Request in the decorator, though. I looked at PEP318, specifically the fourth example, but I'm not quite getting it.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
def login_required(*args, **kw):
    def goto_login(**kw):
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    def decorate(f):
        # args[0] should be request
        args[0].client_session['test'] = True
        logged_in = 0
        if logged_in:
            return f
        else:
            return goto_login
    return decorate


@login_required()
@expose('/hello/<string:name>')
def hello(request, name):
    return render_template('say_hello.html', name=name)
```

but I get an index out of bounds error trying to call `args[0]`.

Is there any way I can get access to the request argument passed into the "hello" function in the "login_required" decorator?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The decorator `login_required` is passed the function (`hello` in this case).

So what you want to do is:

```
def login_required(f):
    # This function is what we "replace" hello with
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        args[0].client_session['test'] = True
        logged_in = 0
        if logged_in:
            return f(*args, **kw)  # Call hello
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Perfect! I was using a different syntax that was used in the "expose" decorator - I'm not sure I understand the alternate syntax.

Answer (score 7):

`kwargs` is a dictionary containing argument as keys and values as values.

So all you need to do is check:
`some_var = kw['my_property']`

Comment: This only works if the function is called via a dict though right ?

Comment: @OliCrt yep. if the function is called like decorated_func(a, b, c), kwargs will be empty.