# Decorators returning function as none if passed as an argument to the decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have been trying to wrap my head around decorators and I found this weird little thing, let's say we have a decorator like

```
import functools
global_event_registration =[]

def handler_all(func):
    if(func):
        global_event_registration.append(func)
    return func
```

which just adds the function to a global list and returns it, and if we run the function we get the expected output

```
@handler_all
def print_yay():
    print('yay!')
print(global_event_registration)
print_yay()
```

output:

```
[<function __main__.print_yay()>]
yay!
```

but if we change the `handler_all` to accept an arbitrary argument let's say `count`, and then run the same thing again, it errors out,

```
def handler_all(func, count=2):
    if(func):
        global_event_registration.append(func)
    return func

@handler_all(count=2)
def print_yay():
 print('yay')
```

it'll error out saying that positional argument `func` is missing, My question is since in the first case, `func` is being passed in implicitly, why is it not the case in the second case one?

Also I found this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851640/python-decorators-using-functools-partial-where-does-func-come-from) which deals with it using `functools.partial` like

```
def handler_all(func=None, count=2):
    if not func:
        return functools.partial(handler_all, count=count)
    if(func):
        func()
        global_event_registration.append(func)
    return func
```

I got the thread's answer that we are just returning a partial function which has the `func` passed to it implicitly but again the same question remains, how did this get the function passed to it vs simply not using it at all? why is it being passed implicitly in the second case and not in the first one since the function definition is the same?

Also another weird thing is,

in this example

```
def test(name="your_name"):
    def decorator(func):
        print(name)
        func()
        return func
    return decorator

@test(name='altair')
def print_yay():
    print('yay')
```

when you run this, the output is

```
altair
yay
```

My question is why? we are just returning the reference the to the inner function and not calling it, so why does it get called?

and if we move the func to the outer function, it works as expected with no output.

```
def test(func):
    def decorator():
        func()
        return func
    return decorator

@test
def print_yay():
    print('yay')
```

In the same nuance, if I define a decorator like this and call the inner function explicitly, which in turn should return the function passed to it but when I run this it returns a `NoneType`, again why?

```
def test(func=None,name="your_name"):
    def decorator(func):
        print(name)
        func()
        return func
    return decorator(func)
```

the output is

```
altair

<function print_yay at 0x7fcf60466440>
```

The new line is returned by the decorator which means the `print` that we passed in as `func` is working fine.
yet if I call `print_yay`, it just says `NoneObject is not callable`.

```
@test(func=print, name='altair')
def print_yay():
    print('yay')

print_yay()
```

output:

```
      1 @test(func=print,name='altair')
      2 def print_yay():
      3     print('yay')
----> 5 print_yay()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Can somebody explain these nuances to me? I am having a hard time figuring out what exactly is happening under the hood and I cant find any resources which will explain this at all.

Comment: Try what is explained in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010080/python-get-original-function-arguments-in-decorator

Comment: yeah I got it, that we simply need to return the inner function and have it pass in an arbitrary number of args and kwargs and then we can execute that function as required. but in the last two cases, just by changing the position of the `func` arg, we get differing outputs

Comment: "we are just returning the reference the to the inner function and not calling it, so why does it get called?" **you are absolutely calling it**, right here: `func()` right after `print(name)`

Comment: yeah but thats inside the inner function right? it should only be called when we call print_yay since thats now equivalent to the inner function. We are just returning the decorator, so why are its contents being executed?

Comment: @Altair21 **no**. You are *not understanding my answer* and what I keep telling you about how the sugar translates. when you do `@test(name='altair')` that is the equivalent of `print_yay = test(name="your_name")(print_yay)`, so *you* are calling `test`, then the sugar calls what is *returned by `test`*, which is the `def decorator` you defined, which calls `func()` (then for some reason does `return func`, which doesn't make any sense)

Comment: When you want your "decorator to take arguments" you basically need **an extra layer**. This is what `partial` is accomplishing

Comment: I think I got it thanks, as for the `return func()`, I just tried passing in the function that the outer function takes to `decorator` and then calling it, just to verify its being passed in correctly and I returned it to see what the return value would look like, just like you do in a normal decorator

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
@decorator(some_arg)
def foo():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = decorator(some_arg)(foo)
```

So just concentrate on this example:

```
def handler_all(func, count=2):
    if(func):
        global_event_registration.append(func)
    return func

@handler_all(count=2)
def print_yay():
     print('yay')
```

So, this is what is happening:

```
>>> def handler_all(func, count=2):
...     if(func):
...         global_event_registration.append(func)
...     return func
...
>>> @handler_all(count=2)
... def print_yay():
...      print('yay')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: handler_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
>>> def print_yay():
...     print("yay")
...
>>> print_yay = handler_all(count=2)(print_yay)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: handler_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
>>>
```

As you say, it errors out because it is missing an argument. And that is happening because **you are calling the decorator before the sugar has a chance to pass the function**. The error occurs before that.

Comment: I got that the function hasnt been passed in, but why does a `functools.partial` work in this case? we are not explicitly passing in the function in there too.

Comment: @Altair21 because then you are *returning a callable*: `return functools.partial(handler_all, count=count)` so then the sugar is `print_yay = handler_all(func=None, count=2)(print_yay)` which is basically `print_yay = functools.partial(handler_all, count=count)(print_yay)` It has nothing to do with explicitly passing in the function. If you use the sugar, it is always implicit

Comment: ah got it, since we are returning a decorator too with the partial, it behaves normally as if the func was passed to it. Would you mind explaining the other cases too? or point me to some resource which really digs down on how its working?

Comment: @Altair21 look, a lot of what you are doing doesn't make sense. Like, just to begin with, `if func` is really strange in your first function. and you keep calling `func()` in places that don't make sense

Comment: yeah, my bad, this was just for debugging purposes, I am just trying to figure out how its being called